# compress a byte array with vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, compression

i want to compress a byte array with vb.net

a try this code But the results are very bad

Array size :
Before compression 32768
After compression 42737

```
    public static byte[] Compress(byte[] data)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        DeflateStream ds = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress);
        ds.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        ds.Flush();
        ds.Close();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
    public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
    {
        const int BUFFER_SIZE = 256;
        byte[] tempArray = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        List<byte[]> tempList = new List<byte[]>();
        int count = 0, length = 0;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
        DeflateStream ds = new DeflateStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress);

        while ((count = ds.Read(tempArray, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
        {
            if (count == BUFFER_SIZE)
            {
                tempList.Add(tempArray);
                tempArray = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            else
            {
                byte[] temp = new byte[count];
                Array.Copy(tempArray, 0, temp, 0, count);
                tempList.Add(temp);
            }
            length += count;
        }

        byte[] retVal = new byte[length];

        count = 0;
        foreach (byte[] temp in tempList)
        {
            Array.Copy(temp, 0, retVal, count, temp.Length);
            count += temp.Length;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

}
}
 pls can you tell why this happened with me ?

Comment: That looks a lot more like C#

Comment: Depending on the nature of tha data to be compressed and the compression algorithm, it is possible that the resulting data is larger than the original data.

Comment: What is the nature, content and formatting of the data you are receiving and trying to compress?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated above, there is no guarantee that the resulting output will be smaller than the input. That being said you may want to try [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)  rather than DeflateStream. Ive had better luck getting a decent compression on average from it. However, if your input data is smaller than around 1000 bytes you might as well store the uncompressed data as you will on average have a larger output size.

Good luck.